# inserting to SqlLite takes too long

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I insert data like this but it takes too long

For 34,000 records it took 20 minutes !! (for example if I insert into SQL Server CE it took only 3 minutes)

```
conn_sql = new SQLiteConnection(conn_str2);
conn_sql.Open();
cmd_sql = conn_sql.CreateCommand();

for (int i = 0; i < iTotalRows; i++)
{
    try 
    { 
        Makat = dsView.Tables["Items"].Rows[i]["Makat"].ToString().Trim(); 
    }
    catch { Makat = ""; }

    try 
    { 
        Barcode = dsView.Tables["Items"].Rows[i]["Barcode"].ToString().Trim(); 
    }
    catch { Barcode = ""; }

    try 
    { 
        Des = dsView.Tables["Items"].Rows[i]["Des"].ToString().Trim(); 
    }
    catch { Des = ""; }

    try 
    { 
         Price = dsView.Tables["Items"].Rows[i]["Price"].ToString().Trim(); 
    }
    catch { Price = ""; }

    SQL = "INSERT INTO Catalog(Makat,Barcode,Des,Price)VALUES('" + Makat + "','" + Barcode + "','" + Des + "','" + Price + "')";
    cmd_sql.CommandText = SQL;
    cmd_sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd_sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //cmd_sql.Dispose();
}
```

How to insert faster ?

Comment: are you update `Tables["Items"]` in your application and insert to `Catalog` table or just read from another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite implicitly wraps queries within a transaction. Beginning and committing transactions in  a loop could be slowing things down. I think you should get a significant boost of speed if you start a transaction and commit it once the loop is completed:

```
conn_sql.Open();
using(var tran = conn_sql.BeginTransaction()) // <--- create a transaction
{
     cmd_sql = conn_sql.CreateCommand();
     cmd_sql.Transaction = tran;   // <--- assign the transaction to the command
              
     for (int i = 0; i < iTotalRows; i++)
     {
          // ...
          cmd_sql.CommandText = SQL;
          cmd_sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd_sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
          //cmd_sql.Dispose();

     }
     tran.Commit(); // <--- commit the transaction
} // <--- transaction will rollback if not committed already
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to use `StringBuilder` for the string concatenation. Secondly, you are making `34k` requests and this is slow, try to make less amount of requests. Let say using StringBuilder concatenate `5k` insert statements in one and fire it in transaction, do this until all your data will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in a single transaction it should be faster:

```
SqlTransaction transaction;
try
{
    conn_sql = new SQLiteConnection(conn_str2);
    conn_sql.Open();
    cmd_sql = conn_sql.CreateCommand();

    transaction = conn_sql.BeginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalRows; i++)
    {
        // create SQL string
        cmd_sql.CommandText = SQL;
        cmd_sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd_sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```